# How to stop browser caching in Django?

Tags: jquery, django, caching

The site I am building is being cached by browser. So when I make any changes in back-end or front-end I need to hard refresh the respective page to see the changes. In order to stop it I used @never_cache as described in django documentation but seems like its not preventing browser to cache page. Then I tried ajax cache false!

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/getData",
  method:"GET",    
  cache: false
}).done(function (res) {
        alert("Success");
});
```

Still not effective! Can anybody help me solving this problem?

Comment: What is your Django version?

Comment: @Selcuk it am using 2.1,but in server its 1.11, so i just tweak in urls to make it fit to 1.11 version.

Comment: For development purpose you can use Disable Cache option provided in network pane of developer tools of browser. However, its strange why `@never_cache` doesn't work. Also just in case you are using Chrome then this issue might be very annoying and will stick around no matter what all you try. I found firefox as a better alternative to test your app in development phase.

Comment: @Paandittya yeah I'm using Chrome.. For development purpose.. And it's very annoying that is cache every pages.. So is not there permanent solution for this? For staging and live?

Comment: In production env using `@never_cache` worked across all browsers, but in local dev env result are inconsistent. In my use case, I was not concerned much about browser so instead of spending time on solving this issue I chose to simply use firefox. But if you want to do it in chrome only then 1) clearing browser cache, then 2) restarting local dev server, then, 4) start new incongnito window, and then 3) Choose "Disable Cache" from chrome developer tools, might work. My advice would be dont invest too much time on solving this right now and go with firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Checking `Disable Cache` in Ddeveloper Tools works

- On Firefox, use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

  [image]

---

- On Chrome, use right click, Inspect

  [image]